# Java Sockets Eclipse Blank Error Popup

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets

I'm trying to learn how to use sockets in Java, using Eclipse as my IDE. The server runs fine, but when I try to run the client I get a blank error popup.

Error:
[image: Blank Error]

Client:

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 9090);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println(input.readLine());
    }
}
```

Server:

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(9090);
        try {
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = listener.accept();
                try {
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    out.println("Test");
                } finally {
                    socket.close();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            listener.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

```
socket.close();
```

to the end of the main function fixed the problem. Eclipse wasn't too helpful in finding that problem, though...

Comment: Enable the **Java Compiler**->Errors/Warnings->Potential resource leak preference. Better yet, use try-with-resources to make sure the socket is closed. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html